# Extending a View and adding views to the layout from XML

Tags: android

I have a TabHost, where the tab content is a ViewFlipper:

```
<TabHost>
    <LinearLayout>
    <TabWidget />
    <FrameLayout>           
        <!-- <include android:id="@+id/my_view_flipper" layout="@layout/my_viewflipper_layout"/> -->
        <com.appz.mobile.android.views.Tab1MyViewFlipper android:id="@+id/my_view_flipper" />
    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

The commented out line in the XML is the current implementation which works just fine. I want to now use my own ViewFlipper class but I can't figure out how to include the `my_viewflipper_layout` in Tab1MyViewFlipper.

```
public class Tab1MyViewFlipper extends ViewFlipper {
    public Tab1MyViewFlipper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Add the views from 'my_viewflipper_layout' here
    }
}
```

Any ideas or a better way to structure this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this was so obvious!

I simply just changed the `ViewFlipper` in `my_viewflipper_layout` to use my custom viewflipper class, durrr!